# ArchUnit ensuring annotation presence

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

Given [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org) library in version **0.12**:

Is it possible to test a scenario "methods annotated with `A` should also be annotated with `B` or be declared in a type annotated with `B`"?

### Example:

**A.java**

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {
}
```

**B.java**

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface B {
}
```

**TestCases.java**

```java
public class TestCases {

    static class ShouldFail {

        @A
        public void m() {
        }
    }

    static class ShouldPass {

        @A
        @B
        public void m() {
        }
    }

    @B
    static class ShouldPassToo {

        @A
        public void m() {
        }
    }
}
```

### What have I tried?

I've thought that `ArchConditions.beDeclaredInClassesThat` would do the job so I've prepared following rule:

```java
MethodsShouldConjunction rule = methods()
    .that()
    .areAnnotatedWith(A.class)
    .should()
    .beAnnotatedWith(B.class)
    .orShould(beDeclaredInClassesThat(areAnnotatedWith(B.class))); //<-- doesn't compile
```

...but apparently I've misunderstood the purpose of mentioned method. Javadoc of that utility wasn't helpful at all. Can I replace the last line with anything working which fulfills the assertion "methods declared in a type annotated with `B`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I've needlessly tried to pass parameter to `orShould` method. To achieve my goal the rule should be extended using parameterless methods:

```java
methods()
    .that()
    .areAnnotatedWith(A.class)
    .should()
    .beAnnotatedWith(B.class)
    .orShould()
    .beDeclaredInClassesThat()
    .areAnnotatedWith(B.class);
```